# Fire TextChanged for textbox when the text changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a text box which I'm filling of date from the jQuery datepicker and the code is as below:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRDate" runat="server" Width="120px" ClientIDMode="Static"  AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRDate_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#test').datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
       minDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
       defaultDate: new Date(),
       onSelect: function(date, obj){
                     $('#txtRDate').val(date);  //Updates value of date 

                 }
 });
 </script>
```

When select date from datepicker the text is changed on textbox but the  `TextChanged` for textbox is not fired.

C# code behind:

```
  protected void txtRDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        GetData(txtRDate.Text);
  }
```

Kindly advise me how to Fire TextChanged for textbox when the text changed by javascript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And How to keep datepicker with date value selected after auto postback event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery  .val() do not trigger onchange 
You have to trigger it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    minDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
    defaultDate: new Date(),

onSelect: function(date, obj){
    $('#txtRDate').val(date);  //Updates value of date 
 $('#txtRDate').trigger('change');
}
});
</script>
```